# Remove leading whitespaces using variable length lookbehind in RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I'm wondering if variable length lookbehind assertions are supported in JavaScript's RegExp engine?

For example, I'm trying to match the string "**variable length**" in the string "**[*a lot of whitespaces and/or tabs*]variable length lookbehind**", and I have something like this but it does not go well in various RegExp testers:

```
^(?<=[ \t]+).+(?= lookbehind)
```

If it's an illegal pattern, what would be a good workaround to it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have look-behind at all. Steven Levithan has [written up a few says to sort of mimic it](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript), which may be helpful.

I don't quite understand your example, because it seems as though this would fit the bill:

```
/^\s+(.+)lookbehind$/
```

...which matches one or more whitespace chars followed by one or more of any character (in a capture group) followed by the word "lookbehind". Used like this:

```
var str = "        variable length lookbehind";
var match = /^\s+(.+)lookbehind$/.exec(str);
```

yields this array:

```
match[0]: |        variable length lookbehind|
match[1]: |variable length|
```

In Javascript, the first entry in the array is the entire matched string, and the subsequent entries are the capture groups.

But you clearly have a good grasp of regex, so I'm not sure that's what you're looking for...

Something to be aware of in this general area is that a number of implementations of RegExp engines in Javascript don't *quite* handle `\s` correctly (they miss out matching some whitespace chars above the ASCII range); see the S_REGEXP_WHITESPACE_CHARACTER_CLASS_BUGGY test [here](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/cft/).

Comment: Hi. No actually I do not have a good understanding of regex at all, as shown by your example, which is way more intuitive than what I came up with. And also good info about array, it did not cross my mind haha. Yes in this case match[1] would be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript regex engine does not support lookbehinds, only lookaheads are supported.
Here you can find a mimicking solution:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Answer (score 2):

**See [Faster JavaScript Trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript)**

It shows numerous ways a trim can be done (none of which require a look-behind) and also compares the speed of the different approaches. If the end-goal includes stripping leading white-space, don't be afraid to break it down into multiple operations.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: +1 I hate to admit it but it's true. Although what I wanted to do is not entirely a trim operation, I could've just used grouping.:)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this would help you with RegExp but if you want to remove whitespaces you can use a trim function

```
function trimAll(sString) {
  while (sString.substring(0, 1) == ' ') {
    sString = sString.substring(1, sString.length);
  }
  while (sString.substring(sString.length - 1, sString.length) == ' ') {
    sString = sString.substring(0, sString.length - 1);
  }
  return sString;
}
```

Otherwise if you want to check string existance you can use indexOf
[IndexOf on StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)